# Rename column name in models file - Sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, model, sequelize.js

In my project I am using PostgreSql as database. I have defined model.js file. I have one column named `question` in `Drisk table`. I would like to rename this column in my model file as `pr_question` How can I achieve this?

models.js

```
module.exports = {
     Drisk: (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
         const Drisk = sequelize.define('drisk', {
             question: {
                 type: DataTypes.NUMBER,
                 allowNull: false,
                 primaryKey: true
             },
             dil: {
                 type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                 allowNull: false
             },
 
         }, {
             freezeTableName: true,
             timestamps: false
         });
    
         Drisk.removeAttribute('id')
    
         return Drisk;
     },
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create new migration file with

```
sequelize migration:create --name alter-drisk-table
```

And

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, DataTypes) => {
    await queryInterface.renameColumn('Drisk', 'question ', 'pr_question')
  },

  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.renameColumn('Drisk', 'pr_question', 'question ')
  }
};
```

Run below command to update

```
sequelize db:migrate
```